# Return after forEach loop is actually returning before it (NODE)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a google cloud function that I need to loop through a series of firestore documents and then do a check on a certain field. Once the check is done it then adds that field to an object that I have called *item*. Once this is done, I then have a `.then()` function that merges *item* into the document.

The problem is that this return within the forEach loop is returning AFTER this final return, meaning that *item* is being added to the document without the required fields.

I believe the issue may be with `Promises` though I am not certain.

Here is my function:

```
function updateReferenceToComplete(refDoc: any, contract_type: string, contract_pdf: string, guarantorData: any, custom_fields: any) {
    let item: any;

    return refDoc.get()
        .then((data: any) => {
            const reference = data.data();

                item = {
                    date_modified: new Date(),
                    date_signed: new Date(),
                    tenancy_offers: {},
                    status: 'complete',
                    agreement_url: contract_pdf,
                    custom_fields: custom_fields,
                };


             Object.keys(reference.tenancy_offers).forEach((key: string) => {
                console.log('KEYS: ', key);
                if (isNull(reference.tenancy_offers[key])) {

                    const offerDoc = db.collection('tenancy_offers').doc(key);

                    return offerDoc.get()
                       .then((offerData: any) => {
                           const offer = offerData.data();
                            if (offer.status === 'incomplete' && !offer.is_deleted) {

                                item.tenancy_offers[key] = new Date();
                                console.log('ITEM IN FOR EACH: ', item);
                            } else {
                                item.tenancy_offers[key] = null;
                            }
                       })
                } else {
                    return null
                }
            });

        }).then(() => {
            console.log('ITEM AFTER LOOP: ', item);
            return refDoc.set(item, {merge: true})
                .then(() => console.log('done'))
                .catch((err: any) => console.log(err))
        })
}
```

So as you can see I console log item during the loop and after the loop, but the log 'AFTER' the loop is logged first meaning that the `tenancy_offer` object remains blank in firestore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`offerDoc.get().then()` is asynchronous and returns a promise. Using `then()` doesn't make your code stop and wait for the promise to resolve - it just returns another promise. Perhaps you want to collect those promises into an array and use `Promise.all()` to wait for all of them to complete before moving on to the next stage.